# Problems with JCO on SAP Cloud Platform (Cloud Foundry)

Tags: cloud-foundry, jco

I want to run a Sprint Boot component on SCP CF that uses JCO to connect to a backend system. I have a working solution with SCP NEO, but with SCP CF I get a runtime error.

Originally I created a Spring Boot Java component using JCO on SCP NEO stack. Everything works fine with that. In a second step I wanted to migrate the component to the Cloud Foundry stack of the SCP. Therefore a did the necessary configuration (destinations etc) and deployed the component  on the SCP CF stack. I was able to deploy my component and call the REST service via Postman but internally when I try to connect to the configured backend destination I get an runtime error
"java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sapjco3 in java.library.path" when I try to create a JCODestination

Seems that the JCO library is not in place. Do I have to explecitely define the JCO library in SCP CF? If yes, how is this done? As said, under SCP NEO I didn't get such errors...

```java
public JCoDestination getJcoDestination(String target, String jcoDestinationName) {

  JCoDestination jcoDestination = null;
  try {
    jcoDestination = JCoDestinationManager.getDestination(jcoDestinationName);
  } catch (JCoException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to create/read the destination files, target="+target+",      
    destinationName="+jcoDestinationName, e);
  }

  return jcoDestination;
}
```

The error log shows:

```java
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sapjco3 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1966)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1134)
    at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.DefaultJCoRuntime.loadJCoLibrary(DefaultJCoRuntime.java:898)
    at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.DefaultJCoRuntime.registerNativeMethods(DefaultJCoRuntime.java:467)
    at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.JCoRuntime.registerNatives(JCoRuntime.java:1554)
    at com.sap.conn.rfc.driver.CpicDriver.<clinit>(CpicDriver.java:885)
    at com.sap.conn.rfc.engine.DefaultRfcRuntime.getVersion(DefaultRfcRuntime.java:36)
    at com.sap.conn.rfc.api.RfcApi.RfcGetVersion(RfcApi.java:236)
    at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.MiddlewareJavaRfc.<clinit>(MiddlewareJavaRfc.java:214)
    at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.DefaultJCoRuntime.initialize(DefaultJCoRuntime.java:98)
    at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.JCoRuntimeFactory.<clinit>(JCoRuntimeFactory.java:23)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forNameFW(Class.java:362)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at com.sap.conn.jco.JCo.createJCo(JCo.java:52)
    at com.sap.conn.jco.JCo.<clinit>(JCo.java:26)
    at com.sap.conn.jco.JCoDestinationManager.getDestination(JCoDestinationManager.java:104)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the SAP Cloud Platforms (Neo + Cloud Foundry) you cannot use JCo Standalone but you have to use the already embedded/integrated JCo version which is capable to communicate via the SAP Cloud Connector.
But the JCo which comes with the SAP Java buildpack for the CF environment cannot be used with Spring Boot applications:
See the limitations listed [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/65de2977205c403bbc107264b8eccf4b/Cloud/en-US/3cee866c27ec4492b789b10c5d52d94b.html):

> It is not possible to use the SAP Java Connector with Spring Boot
>   applications.

So I am afraid that what you are trying to achieve is not possible.
This limitation does not exist for the Neo cloud platform and seems to be the reason why you do not have any issues there.